# tengo que Crear un gráfico de barras (openpyxl.chart.BarChart()) con referencias determinadas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-3.7, python-2.x

tengo que crear un grafico de barras de medallas olipicas con unas referencias
me dan estas referenias

```
#data = openpyxl.chart.Reference(hoja_olimpiadas, min_col=5, min_row=2, max_col=5, max_row=7)
#categs = openpyxl.chart.Reference(hoja_olimpiadas, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=7)
```

lo hecho asi despues de probar cientos de maneras no estoy seguro que sea la mejor manera y tan simple como que al final salga la grafica en la pantalla no se hacerlo la genero pero no sale nada pero creo que esta bien pero al no verla pues no estoy seguro

```
import openpyxl 
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart,Reference 

wb = openpyxl.Workbook() 
sheet = wb.active 
for i in range(10): 
    sheet.append([i]) 
 
values = Reference(sheet, min_col = 5, min_row = 2, 
                         max_col = 5, max_row = 7) 

chart = BarChart() 
chart.add_data(values) 
chart.title = " Medallas olimpicas "
chart.x_axis.title = " X_AXIS "
chart.y_axis.title = " Y_AXIS "
sheet.add_chart(chart, "E2") 
wb.save("barChart.xlsx") 

print("GRAFICA GENERADA")
```

Comment: @abulafia tu editas la pregunta que yo pongo y la ponermejor es así la editas para eso

Comment: Sí, no se leía correctamente el código. La edité para añadir las marcas ``` alrededor del código para que lo formatee correctamente

Comment: Estupendo  gracias , yo llevo poco  aquí y  con esto alucino como esta todo controlado corregido me parece increíble stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Te está faltando información tanto en la hoja de excel porque solo estás rellenando una columna, como en el código, con esto me refiero a que solo le estas pasando una referencia, cuando tienen que ser dos (x,y). También el orden es erróneo al crear el gráfico.
Aquí dejo algunas correcciones ya que también había errores en los nombres de las variables al usarlas

```
import openpyxl 
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart,Reference 

wb = openpyxl.Workbook() 
sheet = wb.active 
# Con este código solo estás rellenando una la primer columna
# para hacer el grafico necesitas los datos de los dos ejes
"""for i in range(10): 
    sheet.append([i])"""

# Agregamos algunos datos de ejemplo en la hoja
datos = [
    ['Pais', 'Oros', 'Platas', 'Bronces', 'Totales'],
    ['A', 18, 14, 10, 42],
    ['B', 13, 20, 11, 44],
    ['C', 12, 9, 5, 26],
    ['D', 9, 8, 7, 24],
    ['E', 7, 10, 5, 22],
    ['F', 5, 8, 10, 23]
]
for fila in datos:
    hoja.append(fila)
    
# Primero se crea el gráfico
chart = BarChart() 
chart.title = " Medallas olimpicas "
chart.style = 10
chart.x_axis.title = " Países "
chart.y_axis.title = " Medallas "
chart.varyColors = True # plus: Asigna colores aleatorios a las barras

# Y luego se asignan las referencias
# De esta manera asignamos el rango del eje y ["E1:E7"]
data = Reference(hoja, min_col=5, min_row=1, max_row=7)
# Y así el rango del eje x ["A2:A7"]
categorias = Reference(hoja, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=7)
chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data = True)
chart.set_categories(categorias)

hoja.add_chart(chart, "A10") 
libro.save("barChart.xlsx") 

print("GRAFICA GENERADA")
```